# Python: Element assignment in a scipy.sparse.diags matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm currently trying to change a row in a matrix which I created using the `scipy.sparse.diags` function. However, it returns the following error saying that I cannot assign to this object:

```
 TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there any way around this without having to change the original vectors used to form the tridiagonal matrix? The following is my code:

```
def Mass_Matrix(x0):

"""Finds the Mass matrix for any non uniform mesh x0"""

x0 = np.array(x0)
N = len(x0) - 1
h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]

a = np.zeros(N+1)
a[0] = h[0]/3
for j in range(1,N):
    a[j] = h[j-1]/3 + h[j]/3
a[N] = h[N-1]/3

b = h/6
c = h/6

data = [a.tolist(), b.tolist(), c.tolist()]
Positions = [0,1,-1]
Mass_Matrix = diags(data, Positions, (N+1,N+1))

return Mass_Matrix


def Initial_U(x0): #BC here

x0 = np.array(x0)
h = x0[1:] - x0[:-1]
N = len(x0) - 1

Mass = Mass_Matrix(x0)

Mass[0] = 0 #ITEM ASSIGNMENT ERROR

print Mass.toarray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sparse matrix defined with your function:

```
x0=np.arange(10)
mm=Mass_Matrix(x0)
```

The `csr` format is the one that is normally used for calculations, such as matrix multiplication, and linalg solve.  It does define assignment, but gives an efficiency warning:

```
In [29]: mmr=mm.tocsr()

In [30]: mmr[0]=0
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:690: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

`lil` works fine

```
In [31]: mml=mm.tolil()

In [32]: mml[0]=0
```

Many of the `sparse` functions and methods convert one format to another to take advantage of their respective strengths.  But the developers haven't implemented all possible combinations.  You need to read the pros and cons of the various formats, and also note the methods for each.